# Send broadcast Push Notification

Tags: c#, azure, push-notification

I am trying to send a broadcast push notification to all registered devices.

I see that there are the following 2 methods in the `NotificationHubClient` :

- `public Task<NotificationOutcome> SendNotificationAsync(Notification notification, string tagExpression);`
- `public Task<NotificationOutcome> SendNotificationAsync(Notification notification, IEnumerable<string> tags);`

In the latter, it states that the `tags` parameter needs to be non-empty and will through an exception if it is empty.

In the former, it accepts a single tag or tag expression.

They mention in the documentation multiple times that you can send broadcast messages to all devices but I cant find an example of this.

Answer (score 0):

There are the following 3 methods in the NotificationHubClient.

You need just this code for broadcasting.

```
public Task<NotificationOutcome> SendNotificationAsync(Notification notification);
```

You don't need `string tagExpression` or `IEnumerable<string>` tags

Comment: Do you have an example because in my case I also want to send notification using tags and broadcast both then how can I do this?